# Android.SMSthief.A2e76 (PUP) in Classes.dex

Tags: android, android-studio-2.2

I recently updated my Android Studio to the latest build and I am facing one issue which is Android.SMSthief.A2e76 (PUP).

I don not know what does this mean but it's being detected by Quick Heal Total Security and I don not know what to do. please let me know what can I do? and is it really the virus or what. as I am having this issue in my all PC. I also checked with a fresh installation of Windows with no data on the HDD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was the issue with Android studio and SDK, I updated today to latest build and now there is no more issue with compilation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks a trajon .. see this :http://www.solvusoft.com/en/malware/trojans/android-smsthief-a/

Comment: hi, thanks for your solution, but it doesn't work. as this virus is injected somehow in classes.dex.